# How to add a dropdown to a Leaflet marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working on a Leaflet map that features a few markers and routes. When a marker is clicked, I need to display a few options like "delete", "stop here for 15 minutes", etc.

All I got to add to Leaflet now is a through `Marker.popup()`. I guess I could restyle the popup to look like I want, but it'd be easier to just use my custom HTML as all I want to see is the dropdown list after one click on the marker.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a select tag with the html inside a bindPopup method

```js
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var popupContent = `
 <select>
    <option value="delete">delete</option>
    <option value="stop here for 15 minutes">stop here for 15 minutes</option>
  </select>
`;

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup(popupContent);
```

```css
#mapid {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css">

<script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js
'></script>
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: Nice approach! However, I was expecting that the marker itself fires the dropdown so I don't have to see anything else than the dropdown list. So far, this is the approach I'll be using: https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu

Comment: Sorry but you did not clarify that! Therefore you want to see only the dropdown and not the popup container. Is that correct? If it is the case check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h146x0qj/)

Comment: Did you check the demo in the previous comment? I updated the code with what you asked for..

Comment: Yes. You merely made transparent the popup. Two clicks are still required. I don't want a select element, I want to add my own HTML snippet positioned where the marker is.